# jQuery survey auto-size/ auto-view not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a survey website with auto-size and auto-view functionality.
So people will see minimal 1 survey question and max 3 survey questions based on their screen size.

I have the following code, but after resizing the next en previous button wont work correct any more. I tried almost everything but i cant get it to work correctly.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var firstdiv;
        var divs = [];
        var view;

        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $("#container").find("div").each(function(){ divs.push(this.id); });
            firstdiv = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).first().attr('id'), divs));
            InitalizeSizes();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            InitalizeSizes();
        });

        function InitalizeSizes() {
            for (i = 0; i <= divs.length; i++) {
                $("#"+divs[i]).hide();
            }

            if(window.innerHeight <= 716){
                $("#"+divs[firstdiv]).show();
                view = 1;
            }
            else if(window.innerHeight > 716 && window.innerHeight <= 1067){
                $("#"+divs[firstdiv]).show();
                $("#"+divs[firstdiv+1]).show();
                view = 2;
            }
            else{
                $("#"+divs[firstdiv]).show();
                $("#"+divs[firstdiv+1]).show();
                $("#"+divs[(firstdiv+2)]).show();
                view = 3;
            }

            var divnumber = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).last().attr('id'), divs));

            $("#btnnext").click(function(){
                if( !($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).last().is('div:last')) ){
                    divnumber = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).last().attr('id'), divs));
                    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                            $("#"+divs[i]).hide();
                    }
                    for (i = 1; i <= view; i++) {                       
                        $("#"+divs[(divnumber+i)]).show();

                    }
                };
            });

            $("#btnback").click(function(){
                if( !($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).first().is('div div:first')) ){
                    divnumber = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).first().attr('id'), divs));
                    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                            $("#"+divs[i]).hide();
                    }
                    for (i = 1; i <= view; i++) {                       
                        $("#"+divs[(divnumber-i)]).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    </script>           
</head>
<body>
    <form id="containerform" action="#">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="div1"><br /><label>Div1</label><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
            <div id="div2"><br /><label>Div2</label><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
            <div id="div3"><br /><label>Div3</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
            <div id="div4"><br /><label>Div4</label><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
            <div id="div5"><br /><label>Div5</label><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
            <div id="div6"><br /><label>Div6</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div>                
            <div id="div7"><br /><label>Div7</label><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
            <div id="div8"><br /><label>Div8</label><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
            <div id="div9"><br /><label>Div9</label><input type="text" name="email" /><input type="submit" value="verzonden"/></div>
            <p id="buttons"><button id="btnback">Previous</button><button id="btnnext">Next</button></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I hope you guys can help me out, because I am breaking my brains for two days now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found it! there where multiple problems.

Like the `<p id="buttons">` must **not** be in the form because it make IE and Edge cry apparently.

And the `$(window).resize(function()` should be `$(window).on('resize',function()` and should be placed in the `$(document).ready(function ()`.

Also the buttonclick and `function InitializeSizes()` should be placed in the `$(document).ready(function ()`.

So that makes the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var divs = [];
        $("#container").find("div").each(function(){ divs.push(this.id); });
        var firstdiv;
        firstdiv = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') != 'none';}).first().attr('id'), divs));    
        var view;
        var divnumber;      

        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $("#container").find("div").each(function(){ divs.push(this.id); });
            InitalizeSizes();
            divnumber = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).last().attr('id'), divs));

            $("#btnnext").click(function(){             
                if( !($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).last().is('div:last')) ){
                    divnumber = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).last().attr('id'), divs));
                    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                            $("#"+divs[i]).css("display","none");
                    }
                    for (i = 1; i <= view; i++) {                       
                        $("#"+divs[(divnumber+i)]).css("display","table-row");
                        firstdiv = divnumber;
                    }
                }
            }); 

            $("#btnback").click(function(){

                if( !($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).first().is('div div:first')) ){
                    console.log(jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).first().attr('id'), divs));
                    divnumber = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).first().attr('id'), divs));
                    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                            $("#"+divs[i]).css("display","none");
                    }
                    for (i = 1; i <= view; i++) {                       
                        $("#"+divs[(divnumber-i)]).css("display","table-row");
                    }
                }
            });

            $(window).on('resize',function(){
                firstdiv = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).first().attr('id'), divs));   
                InitalizeSizes();
            }); 


            function InitalizeSizes() {
                firstdiv = (jQuery.inArray($('#container').children("div").filter(function() {return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';}).first().attr('id'), divs));
                for (i = 0; i <= divs.length; i++) {
                    $("#"+divs[i]).css("display","none");
                }

                if(window.innerHeight <= 716){
                    $("#"+divs[firstdiv]).css("display","table-row");
                    view = 1;
                }
                else if(window.innerHeight > 716 && window.innerHeight <= 1067){
                    $("#"+divs[firstdiv]).css("display","table-row");
                    $("#"+divs[(firstdiv+1)]).css("display","table-row");
                    view = 2;
                }
                else{
                    $("#"+divs[firstdiv]).css("display","table-row");
                    $("#"+divs[(firstdiv+1)]).css("display","table-row");
                    $("#"+divs[(firstdiv+2)]).css("display","table-row");
                    view = 3;
                }                   
            }   
        }); 

    </script>           
</head>
<body>
    <form id="containerform" action="#">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="div1"><br /><label>Div1</label><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
            <div id="div2"><br /><label>Div2</label><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
            <div id="div3"><br /><label>Div3</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
            <div id="div4"><br /><label>Div4</label><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
            <div id="div5"><br /><label>Div5</label><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
            <div id="div6"><br /><label>Div6</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div>                
            <div id="div7"><br /><label>Div7</label><input type="text" name="username" /></div>
            <div id="div8"><br /><label>Div8</label><input type="password" name="password" /></div>
            <div id="div9"><br /><label>Div9</label><input type="text" name="email" /><input type="submit" value="verzonden"/></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p id="buttons"><button id="btnback">Previous</button><button id="btnnext">Next</button></p>
</body>
```

This works cross-browser (I tested it on Firefox, Chrome, IE and Edge) perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using css instead,see if that works

```
//hide
$("#"+divs[i]).css("display","none");
//show
$("#"+divs[i]).css("display","inline");
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reaction Vibhu!

Still the same results.

It works fine at first. But when i click the next button after i resizing the screen it wil go from div1 + div2 to div9.

It must have something to do with the 'firstdiv' or 'divnumber' values, but i just dont see what...

Comment: On running your code(without the style.css) in my browser, when I restore  it is showing one control and on maximizing it is showing two controls.. so jQuery seems to be working,maybe the problem might be with the values of innerheight ,cant really say for sure tho : -)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired behaviour with the following script:

```
set = function (page, width, elements) {

    // Hide every element

    elements.hide();

    // Find number of elements per page

    var n = 1;

    if (width >= 716 && width <= 1076) {
        n = 2;
    } else if (width > 1076) {
        n = 3;
    }

    // Show elements of current page

    var total = elements.length;        
    var start = (page - 1) * n;

    var l = start + n <= total ? start + n : total;

    for (var j = start; j < l; j++) {
        $(elements[j]).show();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Set variables

    var page = 1;
    var width = $(document).width();
    var elements = $('#container div');

    var first = $(elements[0]);
    var last = $(elements[elements.length - 1]);

    // Set page content

    set(page, width, elements);

    // Set event listeners

    $(window).resize(function () {
        width = $(document).width();
        page = 1;
        set(page, width, elements);
    });

    $('#btnback').click(function () {
        if (!first.is(':visible')) {
            page--;
            set(page, width, elements);
        }
    });

    $('#btnnext').click(function () {
        if (!last.is(':visible')) {
            page++;
            set(page, width, elements);
        }
    });
});
```